Followup to Fulton's Young Tableaux
I'm interested in learning more about algebraic combinatorics. I've worked through most of Fulton's Young Tableaux at this point and I am wondering what a logical follow up would be. In general I'm interested in combinatorial algebraic geometry as well as algorithmic / complexity theoretic ideas around combinatorial AG. In the direction of the latter I am currently looking at Cox, Little, and O'Shea's Using Algebraic Geometry. I was looking at Manivel's Symmetric Functions, Schubert Polynomials, and Degeneracy Loci but am open to other suggestions.

There are probably as many answers to this as there are combinatorialists in the field. Sadly Fulton never wrote a followup (or, as it seems, any other book that approaches Young tableaux in readability). Maybe the recent Symmetric Functions by Smirnov and Tutubalina can be seen as a followup (thematically at least), though you are probably better off learning the arrays part from Marc van Leeuwen's papers.
